# How to select 2 items at a time?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I was writing a PascalCaseParser using `Regex.Split` and I came to the desire to select two items from an collection at a time.

This example code demonstrates.

```
void Main()
{
    string pascalCasedString = "JustLikeYouAndMe";
    var words = WordsFromPascalCasedString(pascalCasedString);
    words.Dump();
}

IEnumerable<string> WordsFromPascalCasedString(string pascalCasedString)
{
    var rx = new Regex("([A-Z])");
    return rx.Split(pascalCasedString)
             .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))
             // how to select 2 elements at a time?
             ;
}
```

The result of above code is:

```
IEnumerable<String> (10 items)
J 
ust 
L 
ike 
Y 
ou 
A 
nd 
M 
e
```

Every two elements of the collection make one result that I want the function `WordsFromPascalCasedString` to yield.

My questions is: How would you, in general, deal with a requirement to return two items at a time.  I'm curious if there are any interesting non-brute-force approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with *Simon Belanger*'s answer in this particular case. But in general, to select consecutive pairs, from an `IEnumerable`, you'd use this:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> WordsFromPascalCasedString(string pascalCasedString)
{
    var rx = new Regex("([A-Z])");
    var array = rx.Split(pascalCasedString)
                  .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))
                  .ToArray();
    var items = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length / 2)
                          .Select(i => Tuple.Create(array[i * 2], array[i * 2 + 1]);
}
```

Or this, which takes more effort, but it's reusable and more efficient:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Pairs<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    var array = new T[2];
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var x in input)
    {
        array[i] = x;
        i = (i + 1) % 2;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(array[0], array[1]);
        }
    }
}


IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> WordsFromPascalCasedString(string pascalCasedString)
{
    var rx = new Regex("([A-Z])");
    var output = rx.Split(pascalCasedString)
                   .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c));
    var items = Pairs(output);
}
```

It can easily be extended to groups of `n`:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batches<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, int n)
{
    var array = new T[n];
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var x in input)
    {
        array[i] = x;
        i = (i + 1) % n;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            yield return array.ToArray();
        }
    }

    if (i != 0)
    {
        yield return array.Take(i);
    }
}
```

A similar method exists in [`MoreLINQ`](http://nuget.org/packages/morelinq/).

Answer (score 5):

The regex should be `([A-Z][a-z]*)`. Adjust the last portion if you want to include numbers too. Use `+` instead of `*` if you want at least one lowercase element after the uppercase delimiter.

**Edit** As for the actual question, you will need to materialize and iterate in a `for` loop for better performance (passing the list once). In your specific problem, you can just use `Regex.Matches`

```
var result = Regex.Matches("([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)?", "AbCdEfGhIj")
                  .OfType<Match>()
                  .Where(m => m.Success)
                  .Select(m => Tuple.Create(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value));
```

Comment: +1 for solving my actual issue (thanks)... I'll still be interested if the question I ask gets an answer though...

Comment: What is the other question?

Comment: yeah, I didn't really try to figure out the parser, I was really interested to see of others had wanted to use linq-style select that worked on 2 items at a time... but again I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is to write function that simply returns pairs.

Something like:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<T,T>> Pairs<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    T first = default(T);
    bool hasFirst = false;
    foreach(T item in items)
    {
       if (hasFirst)
          yield return Tuple.Create(first, item);
       else
           first = item;
       hasFirst = !hasFirst;
    }
}
```

`Aggregate` is likely only one one-line approach. This is purely entertainment code due to amount of garbage created on a way, but there is no mutable objects used.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<T,T>> Pairs<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
  return collection
    .Aggregate(
      Tuple.Create(false, default(T), Enumerable.Empty<Tuple<T,T>>()),
         (accumulate, item)=> !accumulate.Item1 ? 
        Tuple.Create(true, item, accumulate.Item3) :
            Tuple.Create(false, default(T),
              accumulate.Item3.Concat(
                 Enumerable.Repeat(Tuple.Create(accumulate.Item2, item), 1))),
      accumulate => accumulate.Item3); 
}
```

`Zip` of odd and even elements (`index %2 ==/!= 0`) is 2 line approach. Note that iterates source collection twice.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<T,T>> Pairs<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
  return collection
   .Where((item, index)=>index %2 == 0)
   .Zip(collection.Where((item, index)=>index %2 != 0),
   (first,second)=> Tuple.Create(first,second));
}
```

Comment: This is pure entertainment answer - p.s.w.g (+1) already covered much nicer version of creating pairs.

Answer (score 2):

This is just to share, I'm throwing the solution I came up with after getting inspired by the other answers.  It is not better than the others...

```
void Main()
{
    string pascalCasedString = "JustLikeYouAndMe";
    var words = WordsFromPascalCasedString(pascalCasedString);
    words.Dump();
}

IEnumerable<string> WordsFromPascalCasedString(string pascalCasedString)
{
    var rx = new Regex("([A-Z])");
    return rx.Split(pascalCasedString)
             .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))
             .InPieces(2)
             .Select(c => c.ElementAt(0) + c.ElementAt(1));
}

static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> InPieces<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, int len)
    {
        if(!seq.Any()) 
            yield break;

        yield return seq.Take(len);

        foreach (var element in InPieces(seq.Skip(len), len))
            yield return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I've seen many 'batching' techniques, but this is the first recursive one I've seen. It may not be the most efficient, but it's definitely creative.